# How can I link the AccountModel Password length DataAnnotation with Membership provider minRequiredPasswordLength?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, data-annotations

When working with asp.net MVC 3, the default website which is installed from the template has an `AccountModel`. Within this, there are `DataAnnotation`s for the password property and here the `MinimumLength` of the `StringLength` is set.

However, within the .NET framework Membership provider, you can set the `minRequiredPasswordLength` via the `web.config` file.

Now if you were to set the `minRequiredPasswordLength` to say 6, yet have the `AccountModel.password` `MinimumLength` set to 1, then you would not be able to register if your password is only 1 character in length. Same the other way around, `minRequiredPasswordLength` is 1 and `MinimumLength` is 6 will not allow registration.

So to me this is a bit backwards. If an installation of the app does not require the a longer password length, then you have to change this in the model.

`DataAnnotations` have to be constant values from what I have read, so is there a way to link these two? Ideally I would like to only have to change the value in the `web.config` and not have to worry about rebuilding projects.

**Edit**

I noticed after looking into this more that Pre MVC 3 Tools Update, the Project Template actually contained a DataAnnotation which linked the Membership `minRequiredPasswordLength` property from the `web.config` to the `AccountModel`
Blogged about it here: http://timjames.me/mvc-3-password-length-dataannotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't.  DataAnnotations are statically compiled into the assembly, and cannot be changed at runtime.

You could create a custom annotation that looked up the length, or use a remote validation to validate against the value in the web.config.  But this would not be using the standard Length attribute.

Comment: Thanks. I would have thought that there would have been an elegant solution to this right from the start within the Project Template, as to me this is a pretty important aspect of the .NET framework membership provider.